# publish web application in azure facing permission issue with office365

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, active-directory, office365, azure-web-app-service

We are doing [Office 365 with asp.net mvc](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start) , in this example working fine for local system,(we are using VS2015), when i publish to azure web application its successfully published.
After open the URL click the Email button go to login page and enter the credentials its successfully logged and redirect to mail page now it showing some error message, but local working fine everything.

Please let me know anything required after publish.

```
 Oops you've reached an error!
We weren't able to process the action you requested. This was caused by an exception in the below table: 
Exception   Cause   Action
AdalException   This exception is thrown when either you have a stale O365 access token that can cause authentication errors, or you attempted to access a resource that you don't have permissions to access.  

You'll may need to refresh the access token. Try signing out and signing back in to the app again, or refreshing the session Click here.


Make sure the app is configured with the correct service permissions in the Services Manager menu. If any of these permissions are not configured, or configured incorrectly, some parts of the app may throw an error. For example  Right click the project, select Connected Service..., and ensure the following permissions are set for this app:

    (Calendar) – Have full access to users’ calendar and Read users' calendar
    (Contacts) – Have full access to users’ contacts and Read users' contacts
    (Mail) - Send mail as a user, Read and write access to users' mail, and Read users' mail
    (Users and Groups) – Enable sign-on and read users’ profiles.
```

Thanks,
hemanth

Comment: Did you  use the same account for testing? Based on the error message, it seems that the account you were longing has no permission for the resource.

Comment: Hi Fei Xue, yes we are using same account and i gave all permissions, i observed problem is ADALTokenCache not generated in published code, but i don't no how to solve the issue